# Реализация фрагмента с картинкой

Tags: java, android

Привет, появилась проблема не могу передать изображение во фрагмент. У меня есть адаптер `RecyclerView` `ProductAdapter`, есть Фрагмент в котором собственно создается список(заголовок и картинка),есть класс `Product` и есть фрагмент, который будет отображать нажатую картинку.не могу понять как и откуда вытягивать определенную картинку. Думаю что из адаптера но сама  картинка задается во фрагменте.

Это код самого адаптера

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {


    private Context mCtx;

    private List<Product> productList;

    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    private Fragment fragment;


    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());

        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(product.getImage()));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }


    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewRating, textViewPrice;

        Button buttonImage;

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        public ProductViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            buttonImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonImage);


            buttonImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    FragmentBigPicture fragmentBigPicture = new FragmentBigPicture();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) mCtx).getFragmentManager();

                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                            .commit();


                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

это код класса

```
public class Product {
//private int id;
private String title;
/*  private String shortdesc;
  private double rating;
  private double price;*/
private int image;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public Product(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Product(String title, int image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}}
```

Это код фрагмента (не обращайте внимания на реализацию создания списка, она будет осуществлена с помощью "парсинга" сайта)

```
public class FragmentImport extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
List<Product> productList;

//the recyclerview
RecyclerView recyclerView;



private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FragmentImport() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentImport.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentImport newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentImport fragment = new FragmentImport();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    productList = new ArrayList<>();


    productList.add(
            new Product("Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)",
                    R.drawable.macbook));

    productList.add(
            new Product(
                    "Dell Inspiron 7000 Core i5 7th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/Windows 10 Home)",
                    R.drawable.dellinspiron));

    productList.add(
            new Product(
                    "Microsoft Surface Pro 4 Core m3 6th Gen - (4 GB/128 GB SSD/Windows 10)",
                    R.drawable.surface));

    ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), productList);


    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}






@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
 interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Это код фрагмента который будет изображение вытягивать

```
public class FragmentBigPicture extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
ImageView imageView2;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FragmentBigPicture() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentBigPicture.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentBigPicture newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentBigPicture fragment = new FragmentBigPicture();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_big_picture, container, false);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    FragmentImport fImport = new FragmentImport();


    return view;
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}}
```

Очень надеюсь, что мне сможете помочь, несколько дней думал как это решить.

Comment: Проблема требует уточнения) Слшиком много кода

Comment: В том месте, где Вы создаете инстанс фрагмента, можно вызвать `getAdapterPosition()` и...

Comment: сможете ,пожалуйста, чуть-чуть по-подробнее

Answer (score 1):

Привет!

Лучший способ, как мне кажется, передать из адаптера int переменную картинки, на которую пользователь нажал, в фрагмент, где находиться RecyclerView и из этого фрагмента запустить фрагмент с картинкой.

Пример: Пользователь нажал на картинку -> из адаптера **ProductAdapter** передается int переменная картинки (поле **int image** из класса **Product**) в фрагмент **FragmentImport**  -> фрагмент **FragmentImport** запускает фрагмент с этой картинкой **FragmentBigPicture**.

Решение:

1. Добавляем интерфейс для взаимодействия адаптера с фрагментом (**FragmentImport**) в класс адаптера (**ProductAdapter**). Код адаптера:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

        //Данные для адаптера
        private List productList;
        //Ссылка на интерфейс, который взаимодействует с фрагментом
        private OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener;

        //Конструктор, который принимает данные и реализацию интерфейса для взаимодействия фрагмента и адаптера
        public ProductAdapter(List items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
            productList = items;
            this.listener = listener;
        }


        @Override
        public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
            return new ProductViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Product product = productList.get(position);
            holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
     holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(product.getImage()));

        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return productList.size();
        }


        public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewRating, textViewPrice;

            Button buttonImage;

            public ImageView getImageView() {
                return imageView;
            }

            public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
                this.imageView = imageView;
            }

            public ProductViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);

                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                buttonImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonImage);


                buttonImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                       // При нажатии на картинку, вызывается метод интерфейса, в
                       // который передается идентификатор нажатой картинки
                      if (listener != null)
                           listener
                               .onClickItemPicture(
                                  productList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage());


                    }
                });
            }
        }

      //Интерфейс для взаимодействия адаптера и фрагмента
      interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
            //Метод, который необходимо реализовать
            void onClickItemPicture(int picNumber);
      }
    }
```

2. Меняем фрагмент, который отображает картинку **FragmentBigPicture**. Необходимо так, чтобы он принимал идентификатор картинки, которую он будет отображать. Передаем идентификатор через аргументы, метод **newInstance(int picNum)**. Код фрагмента **FragmentBigPicture**:

```
public class FragmentBigPicture extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_IMAGE_SRC = "image_resource_id";
    private ImageView imageView2;

    public FragmentBigPicture() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FragmentBigPicture newInstance(int image) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //Кладем идентификатор картинки в аргументы
        args.putInt(ARG_IMAGE_SRC, image);
        FragmentBigPicture fragment = new FragmentBigPicture();
        //Прикрепляем аргументы к фрагменту
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_big_picture, container, false);

        imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        //Получаем картинку из аргументов, если аргументы пусты возвращаем 
        //картинку-заглушку
        int currentImg = getArguments() != null
                ? getArguments().getInt(ARG_IMAGE_SRC)
                : R.drawable.stub;
        //Ставим полученную картинку
        imageView2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), currentImg));

        return view;
}}
```

3. В фрагменте **FragmentImport** соответственно меняем инициализацию адаптера и реализуем метод для вызова фрагмента **FragmentBigPicture**.

```
    public class FragmentImport extends Fragment {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private List productList;

        public FragmentImport() {
        }

        // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static FragmentImport newInstance(int columnCount) {
            FragmentImport fragment = new FragmentImport();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, container, false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

            productList = new ArrayList();

            productList.add(
                    new Product("Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)",
                            R.drawable.macbook));

            productList.add(
                    new Product(
                            "Dell Inspiron 7000 Core i5 7th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/Windows 10 Home)",
                            R.drawable.dellinspiron));

            productList.add(
                    new Product(
                            "Microsoft Surface Pro 4 Core m3 6th Gen - (4 GB/128 GB SSD/Windows 10)",
                            R.drawable.surface));

            ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(productList,
                    //Реализация интерфейса адаптера, которая будет 
                    //вызывать при нажатии на картинку
                    new ProductAdapter.OnListFragmentInteractionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClickItemPicture(int picNumber) {
                          //Наш реализованный метод, который вызывает 
                          //фрагмент FragmentBigPicture 
                          //Создаем фрагмент и 
                          //передаем в него идентификатор картинки
                          FragmentBigPicture fragmentBigPicture = newFragmentBigPicture.newInstance(picNumber);
                          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                        fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                        }
                    });
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return view;
        }

    }
```

Удачи с реализацией!

*PS: В Адаптере не желательно хранить ссылки на фрагмент!*

Comment: Привет, извини,что так долго не отписывал, только успел написать код и тут пару ошибок в ProductAdapter'е пишет Cannot resolve method 'getImage()' и в FragmentImport'е :Cannot resolve symbol 'mCtx' ,Cannot resolve symbol 'fragment' и Cannot resolve symbol 'newIstance'.

Comment: @Iluha_vr я исправил ошибку, по идее должно все работать